# R-Adding rows between rows of a data frame

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, apply, tidyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image]

The second two rows show the Albumin lab values 3 and 63 hours after admission of patient. Between these two rows, I want to add 59 new rows incrementing `HoursFromAdmitLab` values by one each time so I have one row for each hour after admission. for the 59 newly added rows between first and second row, I want to repeat the first row values of every column with the exception that I want `AbnormalityCode` and `Value` be NA and as mentioned before, `HoursFromAdmitLab` be incremented by 1 in each row.

So I want to have one row for each hour after admission (`HoursFromAdmitLab`) and for the hours that lab was not taken I want the `Value` and `AbnormalityCode` as NA that means there is no value available. The second row of my result data frame should look like this:

[image]

I want to repeat this process between second and third row and so on. I tried to this with a loop but it takes for ever and I know there should be a better way.

Comment: See `tidyr::complete` and maybe `fill`

Comment: Please provide data as plain text, not images, so users can easily copy/paste it. Try `dput(yourDataFrame)` or if large, `dput(head(yourDataFrame))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to achieve this is to use two different joins:

1. join with columns which should *not* be filled
2. join with columns which should be filled using a rolling join to fill

The `data.table` package is used for this as the OP has indicated that performance could be crucial for his settings.

```
library(data.table) # CRAN version 1.10.4

# make sure data is in correct order
setorder(setDT(DT), GUID, Hours)

# create sequence of hours for each case
Hours <- DT[, .(Hours = seq(min(Hours), max(Hours))), by = GUID]

# 1st join with columns which should not be filled
tmp <- DT[, c("GUID", "Hours", "Value", "AbnormCode")][Hours, on = c("GUID", "Hours")]

# 2nd, rolling join with columns which should be filled
result <- DT[, -c("Value", "AbnormCode")][tmp, on = .(GUID, Hours), roll = TRUE]

result
#            GUID BirthYearNum GenderCode Hours Value AbnormCode
#  1: 27632200200         1949     Female     3   4.3          N
#  2: 27632200200         1949     Female     4    NA         NA
#  3: 27632200200         1949     Female     5    NA         NA
#  4: 27632200200         1949     Female     6    NA         NA
#  5: 27632200200         1949     Female     7    NA         NA
# ---                                                           
#273: 27632200200         1949     Female   275    NA         NA
#274: 27632200200         1949     Female   276    NA         NA
#275: 27632200200         1949     Female   277    NA         NA
#276: 27632200200         1949     Female   278    NA         NA
#277: 27632200200         1949     Female   279   3.0          L
```

Note that the approach relies on `GUID` being the unique key, i.e., it is assumed that a separate sequence has to be created for each `GUID`.

#### Data

As the OP has failed to provide reproducible data the following data are used:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(
  GUID = "27632200200",
  BirthYearNum = 1949L,
  GenderCode = "Female",
  Hours = c(3, 63, 111, 159, 231, 279),
  Value = c(4.3, 3.8, 3.6, 3.3, 3, 3),
  AbnormCode = c(rep("N", 3), rep("L", 3))
)
DT
#          GUID BirthYearNum GenderCode Hours Value AbnormCode
#1: 27632200200         1949     Female     3   4.3          N
#2: 27632200200         1949     Female    63   3.8          N
#3: 27632200200         1949     Female   111   3.6          N
#4: 27632200200         1949     Female   159   3.3          L
#5: 27632200200         1949     Female   231   3.0          L
#6: 27632200200         1949     Female   279   3.0          L
```

Note that `HoursFromAdmitLab` has been abbreviated to `Hours` and `AbnormalityCode` to `AbnormCode`.

Comment: This is such a fast and elegant solution and it worked perfectly. Thank you.